# jquery required field validator on click of anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I want to validate textbox on click of anchor with jquery required field validator http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation Can you let me know how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Bind a event to the click of this anchor with this:

```
$("#field_id_you_want_to_validate").validate({
  rules: {
    required: true
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Let say you have anchor with id "myAnchor". This is how i write the code

```
$("#myAnchor").click(function(){
// Validate the Textbox that you want 

$("#textboxid").attr('class', 'required');

});
```